# What is the apps script function to reload google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add this function to a button so when the user hits refresh it will refresh the data connected with script will refresh automatically.

Note: I'm not using BigQuery so default refresh option will not appear in google sheets.

I want something like below

```
function reloadData(){

}
```

I will associate this function to a button or something in google sheet.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try ````SpreadsheetApp.flush()````?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try "flush()".

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush

Comment: No Flush is not refreshing my data.